How to Integrate Twilio SMS API in a Flutter App?
Question: I’m working on a Flutter application where I need to send SMS messages using the Twilio API. My goal is to send SMS messages directly from the app to users' phone numbers. I’ve been following the Twilio documentation, but I’m encountering issues during the integration process.
Background:
I’m building this app to provide users with notifications via SMS. Given the scalability and features of Twilio, I’ve decided to use it as my SMS service provider. I’ve set up my Twilio account and retrieved my Account SID, Auth Token, and a Twilio phone number.
What I’m Trying to Achieve:

Objective: Successfully send an SMS using the Twilio API from my Flutter app.

Setup: I’m using Flutter with the http package to make POST requests to Twilio's API.


The Problem:
Here’s the code I’m currently using to send an SMS:
Future<void> sendSms(String to, String message) async {
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages.json'),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$accountSid:$authToken')),
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: {
      'To': to,
      'From': '{Your Twilio Number}',
      'Body': message,
    },
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 201) {
    print('SMS Sent!');
  } else {
    print('Failed to send SMS: ${response.body}');
  }
}

Explanation: This code is supposed to send an SMS using the Twilio API. I’m trying to make a POST request with the necessary authentication and SMS details. However, when I run the code, the API returns an error instead of successfully sending the SMS.
Issue: I’ve checked that my Account SID, Auth Token, and phone numbers are correct, but I’m still receiving an error response.
Request for Help:

Am I handling the API request and authentication correctly in Flutter?
Is there something I’m missing in terms of Flutter’s configuration that could be causing this issue?
Could the issue be related to Flutter’s handling of network requests or the way I’m encoding the credentials?

Additional Context:
I’m relatively new to integrating third-party APIs with Flutter, so any tips or best practices related to this kind of integration would be greatly appreciated.
Error Message:
Here’s the error message I’m receiving:
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "The 'To' number is not a valid phone number.",
  "code": 21211,
  "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21211"
}


Are you including County code. For example India is +91.

What is the value of to for the specific case? And as asked by @KaushikChandru, are you using proper format for To like this: [+] [country code] [subscriber number including area code]?

I read "I’ve checked that ...  are correct" as meets my expectation. How do you know it is correct?
